# Ember - Create item and displaying

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This is part of my code:

```
Calendar.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'year', {path: '/year/:year'}, ->
    @resource 'week', {path: '/week/:week'}, ->
      @resource 'events'

Calendar.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    if @modelFor('week').week
      query =
        year: @modelFor('year').year
        week: @modelFor('week').week
        description: 'test'
      this.store.find('event', query)

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    controller.set 'content', model

  renderTemplate: ->
    if @modelFor('week').week
      @render 'week_events', {into: 'application'}

Calendar.EventsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
      createEvent: (data) ->
        date = new Date(data.date)
        event = this.store.createRecord(Calendar.Event, {eventDate: date, description: 'test'})
        event.save()
```

if i create new item, then i can see it only if i refresh page. If i take items without using query, then i can see new item immediately, without need refresh. And i can't understand why. What i doing wrong?

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: @SteveH. no, everything well.

Comment: When you create a new item, this eventually translates to a POST on your REST resource.  The server's response to the POST should include a JSON representation of the object being added.  If you are using server-side IDs, it will have the server-assigned ID.  My guess is that the adapter's `extractArray` and/or `extractSingle` functions are not working properly.  I would step through this code in the debugger to see what your resource is returning and ensure that those functions I mentioned are working properly.